# Lag with variable offset or equivalent solution in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, logic

I am trying to figure a better way to achieve this:

Given a sample table

```
DATE    PRC_A     PRC_B
05/17   10         10
06/17    X         10
07/17   10         X
08/17   10         X
09/17    X         20
```

**GOAL:** *if there is missing data from `PRC_A` but not from `PRC_B`, calculate the difference in `PRC_B's` prices from such day and PRC_B's previous day. If `PRC_B's` previous day price is also missing, continue going back the calendar until you find a non-empty row.*

For example:

06/17 is missing `prc_A` so the difference between `PRC_B's` prices would be 0. On 09/17 the difference would be *10*, since the next previous data available is on 06/17.

Right now I am using the LAG function to calculate the difference. However I am stuck when the previous row is also empty. I have set a counter, and thought about doing a while loop but there should be a condition before the loop and that is not working. I am new to sql and I am not used to the syntax and rules.
Here is my code thus far. It is not correct but it is my start:

```
DECLARE
counter INT:=1
BEGIN
SELECT ....

 case

   when  prc_A is null and prc_B is not null
   then (prc_B- LAG( prc_B, 1,0) OVER ())  
   when prc_A is null andprc_B is not null and (LAG(prc_B, 1,0) OVER ())  is null then
      case 
          when LAG( prc_B, 2,0) OVER ()   is null 
          then counter = counter +1 and
          (prc_B - LAG( prc_B, counter,0) OVER ())
          end
          else
          0
end as DIFF,

FROM ...
ORDER BY ..

END;
```

So how could I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can all be done, simply and efficiently, in plain SQL - no need for procedural code.

I wasn't sure what output format you desire, but you should be able to adapt the solution to your needs.

From what you described, you are looking for the `LAST_VALUE()` function, rather than `LAG()`. `LAST_VALUE()` allows you to ignore nulls. Pay attention to the windowing clause (`ROWS BETWEEN...`) - the default is to include the current row, and you don't want that, so you must have an explicit windowing clause.

**EDIT**: As @boneist points out in a Comment below, since Oracle 11.2 the function `LAG()` added the `IGNORE NULLS` option - and it has the advantage that by default it will look "back" at earlier rows, starting to the most recent - so the windowing clause will not be needed. In Oracle 11.2 or higher, instead of the `LAST_VALUE()` function shown below, one could use `LAG(prc_b ignore nulls) over (order by dt)`.

```
with
     test_data ( dt, prc_a, prc_b ) as (
       select date '2017-05-01',   10,   10 from dual union all
       select date '2017-06-01', null,   10 from dual union all
       select date '2017-07-01',   10, null from dual union all
       select date '2017-08-01',   10, null from dual union all
       select date '2017-09-01', null,   20 from dual
     )
--  End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins below this line.
select dt, prc_a, prc_b,
       case when prc_a is null 
            then prc_b - last_value(prc_b ignore nulls) over (order by dt
                                rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
       end as prc_b_diff
from   test_data
;

DT              PRC_A      PRC_B PRC_B_DIFF
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2017-05-01         10         10           
2017-06-01                    10          0
2017-07-01         10                      
2017-08-01         10                      
2017-09-01                    20         10
```

Comment: well explained! thank you for introducing me this function

Comment: @mathguy From 11g onwards, [LAG](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652)/LEAD have the ignore nulls function too, so you could simplify your solution.

Comment: @Boneist - Good point! I have only been learning Oracle since last year, so I should have known this - I am only reading from documentation for 11.2 and 12.1; since I never needed this, I never learned it. I'll edit the post to add this alternative.

Comment: @Boneist - I just checked, and to be precise, the option was added in 11.2 (it was not yet available in 11.1).

Comment: @mathguy thanks. That'll teach me for just reading the info off of a google blurb and not investigating further! Plus I only checked the 11.2 documentation..